# API.ai stopped sending to webhook?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

The _actions_on_google_ context stopped appearing in the contexts section, and I think this may be a clue to what's gone wrong.

It's just stopped doing anything, it'll get the required parameter then the JSON says it's sent it to webhook but there's only the 'secure' context in that (I remember seeing an actions on google one by default). When I remove my custom context it doesn't help, and I've updated firebase.

[image]

How do I get this back?

Comment: The subject and your description don't match. Did it stop sending anything at all to your webhook, or just stopped sending some information? Exactly what information are you expecting that it no longer sends? Can you update your question to include the JSON that it *is* sending and possibly JSON that shows what it *was* sending?

Comment: Have you enabled the webhook for the intent? Can you send a screenshot (or copy-paste) of the contents of the popup window when you click "Show JSON"?  What issue are you having with contexts?  Have you check the logs for your webhook serve to see if your webhook is being called?  Have you ensured all required parameters are present in the request so the webhook is called?

Comment: It's okay now, I've recreated some of the functions in my index.js file, and for some reason it's working now? Maybe a syntax error not caught during deployment?

Comment: If/when you've identified you issue, please answer your own question so others who find this question later can have an idea of how to solve their issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue was that I had deleted something in the code, maybe the }); at the end.

If you have the same issue, go OCD through your code and match everything together to check it's all good.